# What's the mistake in the integration of $\int \sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following irrational integral

$I=\int \sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt $

Doing the change: $ t=\frac{1}{2}\sinh(x)$ , $dt= \frac{1}{2}\cosh(x)$

$I=\int \sqrt{1+\sinh^2x}(\frac{1}{2}\cosh x)\,dx =\int \sqrt{\cosh^2x}(\frac{1} {2}\cosh x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int{\cosh^2x}\,dx$

Doing $\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

$I=\frac{1}{2}\int{ (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}})^2 \,dx$$=\frac{1}{8}\int{ (e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}) \,dx$
$=\frac{1}{16} (e^{2x}-e^{-2x}+4x)$

from $ t=\frac{1}{2}\sinh(x)$ ->  $x= arcsinh(2t)$ and $4t=e^x-e^{-x}$ so $16t^2 +2=e^{2x}-e^{-2x}$

then
$I=\frac{1}{16} (e^{2x}-e^{-2x}+4x)=\frac{1}{16} (16t^2 +2+4arcsinh(2t))$$

I saw this solved somewhere else using another method, so I know the $16t^2 +2 $ part of the answer  is wrong, However I can't spot my mistake. Can you spot it?

Comment: I think $16t^2 + 2 = \exp(2x) + \exp(-2x)$, since when you square both sides of the previous line, you get a $+$ on the $\exp(-2x)$ term and not a minus.

Comment: Jeez, you're right!, thanks!

Comment: As Hunter mentioned, you'll get $e^{2x}+e^{-2x}$. Rather use, $\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} = \sinh(2x) = 2\sinh(x)\cosh(x) = 2(2t)\sqrt{1+4t^2}$

Comment: Got it, thank you!